# Is lateral movement and horizontal privilege escalation the same thing?

Tags: threat-modeling

Is [lateral movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Lateral_Movement) and [horizontal privilege escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation#Horizontal) the same thing, what would be the key difference to these two ?

Comment: Those are 2 different actions in 2 different contexts... What context are you talking about? The wiki links I provided explains them ...

Comment: if an attacker move from one user group to another with different permissions to different resources (not necessary more permissions) will that be lateral movement or horizontal privilege escalation ? (And thanks for reading this!)

Comment: The question is: is there "movement" to a new asset or just access on the same asset but with different permissions?

Comment: If it is a new asset would it be - lateral movement and the same asset but with different permissions horizontal privilege escalation?